# Eliminar el outline de un boton en Firefox

Tags: css, botón, firefox

Tengo unos cuantos botones que al dar clic aparece un borde alrededor, intente con outline y border pero no se elimina:

```css
.btn-calc {
 margin: 4px;
 width: 45px;
 height: 45px;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 5px;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 font-size: .9em;
 background: transparent;
 color: #939393;
 outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-calc math" id="AC">c</button>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu código no se ve el borde que muestras en la imagen.

Comment: @JheymanMejia Olvidé mencionar que uso Firefox, ¿qué navegador usas?

Comment: Amigo use tu codigo y no me sale como tu dices, ni en chrome ni en firefox, podras poner mas para tratar de ayudarte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El pseudo-elemento que buscás se llama:

```
.btn-calc::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
}
```

Cabe aclarar que eliminar el outline es una mala práctica en cuanto a experiencia de usuario y accesibilidad, ya que dificulta el uso de las páginas a usuarios que navegan con el teclado en las formas. El outline sirve para saber cuál es el elemento que está activo. Te sugiero que si vas a eliminar el outline, [al menos coloqués otra forma de identificar que el botón está activo](http://www.outlinenone.com/). Por ejemplo, podrías cambiar el estado del botón para que al recibir el foco (`:focus`) tenga una sombra alrededor, que es una forma más sutil de integrarlo a la interfaz.

Te copio ambos ejemplos:

```css
.btn-calc {
 margin: 4px;
 width: 45px;
 height: 45px;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 5px;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 font-size: .9em;
 background: transparent;
 color: #939393;
 outline: none !important;
}

.btn-calc.sombra:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.btn-calc::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>Ejemplo sin outline:</h3>
<button class="btn-calc math" id="AC">c</button>
<h3>Ejemplo con sombra al recibir el foco:</h3>
<button class="btn-calc math sombra" id="AC">c</button>
```

Comment: El pseudo-elemento `:-moz-focus-inner` es una [implementación exclusiva para firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55611340/994322), que debés incluir en adición al CSS del selector de estado `:focus` para eliminar el borde de todos los navegadores.